# Choosing equally spaced points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider the sequence $A_1,A_2,A_3, ..., A_{2n-2}, A_{2n-1}, A_{2n}$ of $2n$ points, spaced equally and clockwise on a circle.

For which $n \geq 2$ can you choose $n$ pairs of points $(A_i, A_j)$ such that every point is part of exactly one pair and every distance from $\{0,1, ..., n-1\}$ is covered by some pair $(A_i, A_j)$.
A distance of a pair is defined by the smallest number of points that lie between $A_i$ and $A_j$.

For example, $n=4$ works:
The sequence beeing $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, A_7, A_8$, we can choose pairs $(A_2, A_3), (A_6, A_8), (A_4, A_7), (A_1, A_5)$ with distances $0,1,2,3$ respectively, satisfying the condition.

Comment: it may have sth to do with [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)?

Comment: @C.C. The question can be phrased as: for what $n$ does a [$(1,1)$-biregular graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph) with $n$ edges admit a [graceful labeling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling)?

Comment: You are using $n$ for two different things. You should change the letter used for the subindex of the pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @C.C. idea about a connection with graph theory, I have first searched about [graceful labeling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling) of graphs and found [A Dynamic Survey of Graph Labeling](https://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds6/ds6v25-2022.pdf) by Joseph A. Gallian, and there, on section 2.5, "Disconnected Graphs", a reference to [Skolem Sequence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkolemSequence.html), which is exactly what you are looking for.

The 1957 paper [On certain distributions of integers in pairs with given differences](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/10490/8511) by Th. Skolem proves that a Skolem sequence of length $2n$ exists if and only if $n \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$.

Here I report the proof that no sequence can exist with $n \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$. Proving that a sequence always exists for $n \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$ is longer (see the article).

Let $(a_k,b_k)$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ be the chosen couples in $(1,2,\ldots,2n)$ with $a_k \lt b_k$. Therefore:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

and:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k+a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k = n(2n+1)$$

adding the two equations yields:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n b_k = \frac{n(5n+3)}{4}$$

which is an integer only when $n \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Thanks, great work! Beautiful how intertwined math is.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer but a long comment containing some experimental evidence for further analysis.

If I interpret the question correctly, the distance is measured clockwise, so everything is equivalent to considering the sequence of numbers $(1,2,\ldots,2n-1,2n)$ instead of a circle. Also, in the following, I will use distances computed as the plain difference between the two points in the couple, therefore leading to differences $1,2,\ldots,n$ rather than $0,1,\ldots,n-1$.

The problem can be modeled as a linear programming problem with binary variables, with variables $x_{i,j}, 1 \le i \lt j \le 2n$. $x_{i,j} = 1$ when the couple $(i,j)$ is chosen for the distance $j-i$, $x_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise.

The problem is then e.g. minimize $x_{2n-1,2n}$ subject to:

$$\sum_{k = i \space \lor \space k = j} x_{i,j} = 1, k=1,\ldots,2n$$

$$\sum_{k = j-i} x_{i,j} \ge 1, k=1,\ldots,n$$

I chose just a random objective function and also the second constraint could be replaced with an equality.

For example for $n=4$ we have:

```
Minimize
 obj: x7,8
Subject To
x1,2 + x1,3 + x1,4 + x1,5 + x1,6 + x1,7 + x1,8 = 1
x1,2 + x2,3 + x2,4 + x2,5 + x2,6 + x2,7 + x2,8 = 1
x1,3 + x2,3 + x3,4 + x3,5 + x3,6 + x3,7 + x3,8 = 1
x1,4 + x2,4 + x3,4 + x4,5 + x4,6 + x4,7 + x4,8 = 1
x1,5 + x2,5 + x3,5 + x4,5 + x5,6 + x5,7 + x5,8 = 1
x1,6 + x2,6 + x3,6 + x4,6 + x5,6 + x6,7 + x6,8 = 1
x1,7 + x2,7 + x3,7 + x4,7 + x5,7 + x6,7 + x7,8 = 1
x1,8 + x2,8 + x3,8 + x4,8 + x5,8 + x6,8 + x7,8 = 1
x1,2 + x2,3 + x3,4 + x4,5 + x5,6 + x6,7 + x7,8 >= 1
x1,3 + x2,4 + x3,5 + x4,6 + x5,7 + x6,8 >= 1
x1,4 + x2,5 + x3,6 + x4,7 + x5,8 >= 1
x1,5 + x2,6 + x3,7 + x4,8 >= 1
Binary
 x1,2 x1,3 x1,4 x1,5 x1,6 x1,7 x1,8 x2,3 x2,4 x2,5 x2,6 x2,7 x2,8 x3,4 x3,5 x3,6 x3,7 x3,8 x4,5 x4,6 x4,7 x4,8 x5,6 x5,7 x5,8 x6,7 x6,8 x7,8
End
```

You can submit the problem for free as an LP file at the [NEOS server](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/lp:Gurobi/LP.html) (check "Return .sol file" and add an email address).

I have tried all $1 \le n \le 18$. Here are some solutions:

$$n = 5: (1,5), (2,7), (3,4), (6,9), (8,10)$$
$$n = 8: (1,6), (2,8), (3,7), (4,11), (5,13), (9,10), (12,15), (14,16)$$
$$n = 9: (1,7), (2,9), (3,11), (4,8), (5,10), (6,15), (12,13), (14,17), (16,18)$$

It seems from the results that the problem has a solution if and only if:

$$n \equiv 0,1 \mod 4$$

But now we need a proof of that...

Comment: thank you for this great experimental evidence! The proof seems to be tricky though. I’m not even sure where to start exactly